# How to create automatic a list of items used in a LaTeX-document?

Tags: list, latex, automation, tex

I want to add items in a LaTeX-document. Say for example, that I want add hints to the document. I create a command, so I can call something similar to this:

```
\hint{foocareful}{Be careful with foo!}{foo is a very precious item and can easily be broken. Be careful, especially don't throw foo.}
```

This will be formatted in special way, to make it easy for the reader to recognize it as a hint. It gets a label, that can be referenced in the example with 'foocareful'.

In the appendix I want to add a list of all hints with references to them. Something like:

```
\begin{enumerate}
   ...
   \item Be careful with foo! (\pageref{foocareful})
   ...
\end{enumerate}
```

But naturally I don't want to maintain this list by hand. How can I create automatically such a list?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the `float` package. I think that, at least, the `floatrow` package can also do what you want, and may also be more flexible. See you go, though.

Here's an example of something like you're trying to do using `float`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{hintbox}{H}{hnt}
\floatname{hintbox}{Hint}

\newcommand\hint[2]{%
  \begin{hintbox}
    #2
    \caption{#1}
  \end{hintbox}}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}

\hint{Be careful with foo!\label{foocareful}}{%
  foo is a very precious item and can easily be broken. 
  Be careful, especially don't throw foo.}

\hint{Don't worry about bar!\label{foocareful}}{%
  Unlike foo, bar is pretty easily to get along with.}

\section{End}

\listof{hintbox}{List of Hints}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have not done this in years, but I would look at the LaTeX source code for \tableofcontents and \listoffigures.  I think the mechanism is generic and you can expand it to include your own lists.